# Запятые в сложных предложениях

Tags: пунктуация

Вот такое предложение (в компьютерной игре увидел): "Похоже, они не поняли(,) в чём там дело." Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли в вышеозначенном предложении запятая? В тексте игры запятая была, но, как мне кажется, она там лишняя.

Comment: Что-то всё слиплось в тексте. И в игре также?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, они не поняли, **в чём там дело**.

Запятая нужна, это **сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным**, В ЧЁМ ― союзное слово, придаточное предложение неполное.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.Меня смутило сие союзное слово.Если бы предложение выглядело так:"Похоже,они не поняли,что там произошло",то тогда бы всё было понятно.